# Are called shots allowed with ranged touch spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, ranged-attack

This came up in an encounter where the players were going up against some "Romero" zombies that required destruction of the brain to kill. A wizard asked, "Can I make a called shot to the head with [Scorching Ray](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Scorching_Ray)?"

I remembered the "weapon-like spell" rules from Complete Arcane about critical hits and combat themed feats. Scorching Ray was one of the examples of the spells.

I have not came across rules regarding called shots and spells that I can remember. My answer, not wanting to stop the flow of combat was, "Sure, go for it." She took her penalty and proceeded with her attack.

Now that everything is over with, was my off-the-cuff ruling justified?

Called Shot Rules: Torn Asunder (Bastion Press).

Comment: I'm sure a duplicate of this was asked in the last year, albeit with different wording, but I can't find it. Short answer: yes, if it requires a to hit roll then it can use all of the attack rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes, your ruling appears correct

Creech and Ruesch's *[Torn](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592630073) [Asunder](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/27822/Torn-Asunder-Critical-Hits?it=1)* (2003) from [Bastion Press](http://www.bastionpress.com/) says that

> Once these criteria are met you can attempt a *called shot*. You receive a called shot penalty to your attack roll, as per the chart below for the appropriate body location. (28)

Targeting the head causes the attacker to suffer a −8 called shot penalty on the attack roll. No limits are specified on what effects can or can't *use* these called shot rules, but an attacker using an effect that *doesn't* require an attack roll shouldn't be able to use these called shot rules *at all*. As the spell *[scorching ray](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/scorchingRay.htm)* requires an attack roll, it appears legit to use the spell with these called shot rules.